# starting neo4j data at user defined directory

Tags: neo4j, startup

I created a directory where I'm storing my current graph.db which is different than the default location of /var/lib/neo4j/data/database. I changed my neo4j.config file providing new location of the database as dbms.directories.data=/neo4j/data, but somehow I cannot start the neo4j server using systemctl  start neo4j

Comment: What does the log say (`journalctl -u neo4j`)?

Answer (score 0):

When using a deb or rpm distribution package (I assume you are because you are using systemctl to start the database), the database is run under `neo4j` user by default and this user needs to have write permissions to the data directory.

Does the user have permissions to write to your new `/neo4j/data` directory?